# Postgresql merge same columns from the JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, join

I formed the question a bit silly. But let me express m problem on a example I Am struggling with.

My query gives me the following result below: 
[image]

As you can see, everything is the same except the last column. How can I join the results into one row with both values for the last column.

My query:

```
select tp.tp_vorname as PatientFirstName, tp.tp_nachname as PatientLastName,
       tp.tp_geburtsdatum as patientBirthday, pt.pt_id, te.te_startzeit as StartTime, 
       te.te_endzeit As EndTime, te_datecreated as DateCreated, tpw.li_id_warnungen as Warning
from termin_patient tp
INNER JOIN patienten_termin pt
    on tp.tp_id = pt.tp_id
INNER JOIN termin te
    on te.te_id = pt.pt_id
LEFT JOIN terminpatient_warnungen tpw
on tp.tp_id = tpw.tp_id
where pt.pt_id = te.te_id and tp.tp_id=91168 and 
      te.te_startzeit >= '2017-05-24' 
  AND te.te_startzeit <  '2017-06-02'
```

Comment: Could you share the result you'd want to get? It would make the question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` on all `SELECT` columns (but not on the last - `tpw.li_id_warnungen`) and aggregate the last column into one field.

**Solution for PostgreSQL:**

You can use the following solution using `GROUP BY` and [`STRING_AGG`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html). To use the column `tpw.li_id_warnungen` on `STRING_AGG` you have to `CAST` the value to `TEXT`. Another solution instead of using `CAST` could be to use the direct cast `tpw.li_id_warnungen::text` on the column.

```
SELECT 
    tp.tp_vorname AS PatientFirstName, 
    tp.tp_nachname AS PatientLastName,
    tp.tp_geburtsdatum AS patientBirthday, 
    pt.pt_id, 
    te.te_startzeit AS StartTime, 
    te.te_endzeit AS EndTime, 
    te_datecreated AS DateCreated, 
    STRING_AGG(CAST(tpw.li_id_warnungen AS TEXT), ',') AS Warning
FROM 
    termin_patient tp INNER JOIN patienten_termin pt ON tp.tp_id = pt.tp_id
    INNER JOIN termin te ON te.te_id = pt.pt_id
    LEFT JOIN terminpatient_warnungen tpw ON tp.tp_id = tpw.tp_id
WHERE 
    pt.pt_id = te.te_id 
    AND tp.tp_id = 91168 
    AND te.te_startzeit >= '2017-05-24' 
    AND te.te_startzeit < '2017-06-02' 
GROUP BY 
    tp.tp_vorname, 
    tp.tp_nachname, 
    tp.tp_geburtsdatum, 
    pt.pt_id, 
    te.te_endzeit, 
    te_datecreated
```

---

With the additional warning names (described in comments) your query would look like this (no need for `CAST` or direct cast anymore):

```
SELECT 
    tp.tp_vorname AS PatientFirstName, 
    tp.tp_nachname AS PatientLastName,
    tp.tp_geburtsdatum AS patientBirthday, 
    pt.pt_id, 
    te.te_startzeit AS StartTime, 
    te.te_endzeit AS EndTime, 
    te_datecreated AS DateCreated, 
    STRING_AGG(lip.li_name, ',') AS Warning
FROM 
    termin_patient tp INNER JOIN patienten_termin pt ON tp.tp_id = pt.tp_id
    INNER JOIN termin te ON te.te_id = pt.pt_id
    LEFT JOIN terminpatient_warnungen tpw ON tp.tp_id = tpw.tp_id 
    LEFT JOIN li_patientenwarnung lip ON tpw.li_id_warnungen = lip.li_id
WHERE 
    pt.pt_id = te.te_id 
    AND tp.tp_id = 91168 
    AND te.te_startzeit >= '2017-05-24' 
    AND te.te_startzeit < '2017-06-02' 
GROUP BY 
    tp.tp_vorname, 
    tp.tp_nachname, 
    tp.tp_geburtsdatum, 
    pt.pt_id, 
    te.te_endzeit, 
    te_datecreated
```

**Solution for MySQL:**

You can use the following solution on MySQL using `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT 
    tp.tp_vorname AS PatientFirstName, 
    tp.tp_nachname AS PatientLastName,
    tp.tp_geburtsdatum AS patientBirthday, 
    pt.pt_id, 
    te.te_startzeit AS StartTime, 
    te.te_endzeit AS EndTime, 
    te_datecreated AS DateCreated, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(tpw.li_id_warnungen) as Warning
FROM 
    termin_patient tp INNER JOIN patienten_termin pt ON tp.tp_id = pt.tp_id
    INNER JOIN termin te ON te.te_id = pt.pt_id
    LEFT JOIN terminpatient_warnungen tpw ON tp.tp_id = tpw.tp_id
    LEFT JOIN li_patientenwarnung lip ON tpw.li_id_warnungen = lip.li_id
WHERE 
    pt.pt_id = te.te_id 
    AND tp.tp_id=91168 
    AND te.te_startzeit >= '2017-05-24' 
    AND te.te_startzeit <  '2017-06-02' 
GROUP BY 
    tp.tp_vorname,
    tp.tp_nachname, 
    tp.tp_geburtsdatum,
    pt.pt_id,
    te.te_endzeit,
    te_datecreated
```

---

With the additional warning names (described in comments) your query would look like this:

```
SELECT 
    tp.tp_vorname AS PatientFirstName, 
    tp.tp_nachname AS PatientLastName,
    tp.tp_geburtsdatum AS patientBirthday, 
    pt.pt_id, 
    te.te_startzeit AS StartTime, 
    te.te_endzeit AS EndTime, 
    te_datecreated AS DateCreated, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(lip.li_name) as Warning
FROM 
    termin_patient tp INNER JOIN patienten_termin pt ON tp.tp_id = pt.tp_id
    INNER JOIN termin te ON te.te_id = pt.pt_id
    LEFT JOIN terminpatient_warnungen tpw ON tp.tp_id = tpw.tp_id
WHERE 
    pt.pt_id = te.te_id 
    AND tp.tp_id=91168 
    AND te.te_startzeit >= '2017-05-24' 
    AND te.te_startzeit <  '2017-06-02' 
GROUP BY 
    tp.tp_vorname,
    tp.tp_nachname, 
    tp.tp_geburtsdatum,
    pt.pt_id,
    te.te_endzeit,
    te_datecreated
```

Comment: function string_agg(bigint, unknown) does not exist

Comment: @Jacob You didn't tell us it was an integer column.

Comment: Yes sorry for that. It's an int column

Comment: Sebastian Brosch could you help just a little bit. How can I get names for warning id. The names are in a separate table li_patientenwarnung where there are two column li_name and li_id

Comment: Thank you soo much!